# Variables null between functions controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controlleras

i'm kinnda new in AngularJS. I'm trying to make a controllerAs controller:

```
 var vm = this;
    vm.accounts = [];
    vm.authorized = false;
    vm.title = 'LoginPage';
```

A function which i use to store JsonData with accounts in the vm.accounts:

```
 function login() {
        try {
            return dataservice.login().then(function (data) {
                this.accounts = data;

                return this.accounts;
            })
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

All are corectly and works perfectly. The problem is :when i try to access vm.accounts like this :

```
function checkLogin(){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.accounts.length; i++) {
        if (this.accounts[i].name == "Vlad")
            this.authorized = true;
    }
```

all variables, even "i" are null, what's the problem?

Here is my full .js source code:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.login')
    .controller('login', Login);

/* @ngInject */
function Login(dataservice, logger) {
    /*jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;
    vm.accounts = [];
    vm.authorized = false;
    vm.title = 'LoginPage';

    login();
    checkLogin();
    function login() {
        try {
            return dataservice.login().then(function (data) {
                this.accounts = data;

                return this.accounts;
            })
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
 function checkLogin(){
for (var i = 0; i < this.accounts.length; i++) {
    if (this.accounts[i].name == "Vlad")
        this.authorized = true;
       }
     }
   }
})();
```

And the dataservice:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('dataservice', dataservice);

/* @ngInject */
function dataservice($http, $location, $q, exception, logger) {
    var isPrimed = false;
    var primePromise;

    var service = {
        getAvengersCast: getAvengersCast,
        getAvengerCount: getAvengerCount,
        getAvengers: getAvengers,

        login:login,
        ready: ready
    };

    return service;



    function login() {
        return $http.get('/api/accounts')
            .then(getAccounts)
            .catch(function(message) {
                exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getAccounts')(message);
                $location.url('/');
            });
        function getAccounts(data,status,headers,config) {
            console.log(data.data[0]);
                return data.data[0].data.results;

        }
    }



    function getAvengers() {
        return $http.get('/api/maa')
            .then(getAvengersComplete)
            .catch(function(message) {
                exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getAvengers')(message);
                $location.url('/');
            });

        function getAvengersComplete(data, status, headers, config) {
            return data.data[0].data.results;
        }
    }

    function getAvengerCount() {
        var count = 0;
        return getAvengersCast()
            .then(getAvengersCastComplete)
            .catch(exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getAvengerCount'));

        function getAvengersCastComplete (data) {
            count = data.length;
            return $q.when(count);
        }
    }

    function getAvengersCast() {
        var cast = [
            {name: 'Robert Downey Jr.', character: 'Tony Stark / Iron Man'},
            {name: 'Chris Hemsworth', character: 'Thor'},
            {name: 'Chris Evans', character: 'Steve Rogers / Captain America'},
            {name: 'Mark Ruffalo', character: 'Bruce Banner / The Hulk'},
            {name: 'Scarlett Johansson', character: 'Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow'},
            {name: 'Jeremy Renner', character: 'Clint Barton / Hawkeye'},
            {name: 'Gwyneth Paltrow', character: 'Pepper Potts'},
            {name: 'Samuel L. Jackson', character: 'Nick Fury'},
            {name: 'Paul Bettany', character: 'Jarvis'},
            {name: 'Tom Hiddleston', character: 'Loki'},
            {name: 'Clark Gregg', character: 'Agent Phil Coulson'},
            {name: 'Clark Gregg', character: 'Agent Phil Coulson'},
            {name: 'Clark Gregg', character: 'Agent Phil Coulson'},
            {name: 'Clark Gregg', character: 'Agent Phil Coulson'},
            {name: 'Clark Gregg', character: 'Agent Phil Coulson'}

        ];
        return $q.when(cast);
    }

    function prime() {
        // This function can only be called once.
        if (primePromise) {
            return primePromise;
        }

        primePromise = $q.when(true).then(success);
        return primePromise;

        function success() {
            isPrimed = true;
            logger.info('Primed data');
        }
    }

    function ready(nextPromises) {
        var readyPromise = primePromise || prime();

        return readyPromise
            .then(function() { return $q.all(nextPromises); })
            .catch(exception.catcher('"ready" function failed'));
    }


  }
 })();
```

The data returned:

```
   [
     {
"data": {
  "results":[
    { "name": "Vlad"},
    {"name":"Adi"},
    {"name":"Admin"}
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you include the code for dataservice in your post?

Comment: Alright, check it now :)